# How to determine whether a planar graph can be generated by a degree sequence?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

> For the following degree sequences of graphs,
>
> $2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,5,5\\1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3$
>
> which can be the degree sequence of a simple undirected
> graph that is connected and planar?

I think only the second one can be a valid sequence. Is there a general rule to judge whether a degree sequence can generate a planar graph?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/125664/755, https://mathoverflow.net/q/119887/37212

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it will require some thought on whether a degree sequence is that of a planar graph. For example, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2239646/400626) for some possible strategies, which include using Kuratowski's Theorem, or the well known edge bound $3n - 6$. You can also compute the average degree, which for a planar graph must be strictly less than 6. (See [Planarity Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Other_planarity_criteria).) You'll notice a lot of the time we check to see if a graph violates any of the criterion.

Both sequences may represent a planar graph.

For $2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,5,5$, you may notice several things. Since we're assuming $G$ is connected, $G$ cannot be a tree (there are no degree $1$ vertices) and thus has a cycle. However, $|E(G)| = 16 \le 3(10) - 6 = 24$, so no luck there (remember, we can only use this bound to prove a graph is *non-planar*.) Perhaps after playing around you might think that there is a planar graph, and you'd be right. Using the [Havel--Hakimi Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Havel%E2%80%93Hakimi_algorithm), stopping short when I obtained the degree sequence of the path on $8$ vertices, we find the following graph:

[image: Planar graph with first degree sequence.]

From this example we see that it's not necessarily the case that $G$ has a cycle but no triangle (which would have enabled us to use the improved bound of $2n-4$). Even then, $|E(G)| = 16 = 2(10) - 4$.

For $1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3$, you can quickly notice that this graph cannot contain $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ as a subdivision and thus *must* be planar. This uses Kuratowski's Theorem. It also shouldn't be too hard to find a tree with this degree sequence.

For the first sequence, you may immediately notice that $G$ cannot have a $K_5$ subdivision, however $K_{3,3}$ may require more reasoning. I.e., unlike the second sequence, we've shown the first sequence *can* represent a planar graph, we haven't shown that it *must*.